# How to make usb port static?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, usb, debian

Is there's any way I can fix usb port in Debian linux? For instance, I plugged in usb to serial cable(Cable A) and Debian assigned it to /dev/ttyUSB0. After that i plugged in another usb to serial(Cable B) and it was assigned to /dev/ttyUSB1.

I understood that if I want Cable A to always be assign to /dev/ttyUSB0, I have to plug it in before I insert Cable B. Are there any alternatives if I want Cable A to always be assign to /dev/ttyUSB0 and Cable B to /dev/ttyUSB1 regardless which cable I plug in first or whatever USB port I plugged it in?

I'm open to any suggestion on how to do this and I can write c++ to handle this if needed.

Comment: I don't think it should matter which port you plug which cable or device into. You should query the USB port once it is plugged in to determine what device is plugged into it

Comment: Okay, I can try but is there's any other attribute I can get from the device connected to it other than idVendor and idProduct? (Maybe something like mac address of the device).

Comment: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml#DeviceDescriptors

Answer (score 1):

udev rules were designed for this task:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name
http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

I think on Debian the rules files are in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
Once you have edited the rules you can usually run `udevadm --trigger action=change` to run the new rules, but sometimes I've seen it take a reboot to get them to take affect.

The most common reason to do this is to give a specific device a unique name instead of a specific port, but it is usually possible to give ports names.  I do not know the exact rule at the moment, but this should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes I've read that I can use udev for this. But the problem in most example is all of it use idVendor and idProduct as an attribute which I don't think possible in my case. idVendor and idProduct is the id of usb to serial cable itself and not the end device connected to that cable. So, if I'm using two similar cable from the same manufacturer, I might get a conflict.

Comment: You may be able to use ATTRS{serial} if your cable has a serial number.  You can probably use `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)` to look at all of the available attributes for your device.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mount/Umount/Remount functions from sys/mount.h.
With the appropriate parameters.
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mount_002dUnmount_002dRemount.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using udev you'll find information at that page http://wiki.debian.org/udev

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this depends on the usb2uart controller. some of them does not have a serial number. so one device exactly looks like another from OS point of view.

In this case they are indistinguishable.